# How can I know where the "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered] error" is in my code?

Tags: go, stack-trace

The code doesn't matter, I need to know how to interpret the invalid memory address errors.

For example, this error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x8ea36d]

goroutine 140 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.2({0xb59300, 0x1214030})
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1526 +0x24e
testing.tRunner.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1529 +0x39f
panic({0xb59300, 0x1214030})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:884 +0x213
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.newDatabase(0x0, {0xc0003a6378, 0x6}, {0x0?, 0x599?, 0x527dc0?})
    /home/cesar/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.6/mongo/database.go:47 +0xcd
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Client).Database(...)
    /home/cesar/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.6/mongo/client.go:627
github.com/mar-cial/items/db.TestInsertItem(0x0?)
    /home/cesar/dev/items/db/client_test.go:44 +0xd5
testing.tRunner(0xc00050ba00, 0xc6a030)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1576 +0x10b
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1629 +0x3ea
```

Where does it tell me exactly what produced the error? Does it display a specific line or I can only know the file or what?

Comment: It happened in newDatabase call. First arg is zero which makes me suspect Client is nil

Comment: When reading a stack trace, it is generally recommended to read it from top to bottom. The topmost line usually represents the most recent function call, which is closest to the point where the error occurred. As you move down the stack trace, you go back in time, traversing the function calls that led to the error.  Check out `/home/cesar/dev/items/db/client_test.go:44 +0xd5`